# Realm+Unity При открытии БД ошибка SessionException: Read-only file system

Tags: android, unity3d, realm, realm-database, realm-android

Хочу использовать локальную БД для мобильных устройств Realm DB. Установил **Realm SDK для Unity** (https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/unity).

В редакторе Unity все работает, на устройствах Android выдает ошибку "**SessionException: Read-only file system**" в момент выполнения открытия БД (последняя строчка):

```
string fileNameOnly = "mydb.realm";
string fileNameWithPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileNameOnly; // Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileNameOnly);
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration(fileNameWithPath);
Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

Хотя файл /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxxx/files/mydb.realm совершенно точно существует, и даже только что создан из приложения, проверен на существование, проверены атрибуты файла, при установке приложения запрошены права на extenal storage (хотя это уже лишнее). Path.Combine давал лишнюю косую черту в имени файла, хотя это никогда раньше не мешало, но заменил его на конкатенацию. Пробовал объединить все dll проекта в одну, не помогло. Что же я еще не сделал для успешного успеха?

Главное, Realm рядом с файлом успешно создает вспомогательную папку mydb.realm.management и файл mydb.realm.lock, и ничего ему не мешает.

Версия Realm SDK 10.3.0, Unity 2020.3.12. Устройство MEIZU M5 (Android 6.0) и другие.

Раньше использовал SQLite (LibSQLite), но возникли проблемы на устройствах с процессором ARM64, которые решить не удалось.

Вопрос: **как открыть БД Realm на Android без ошибки "Read-only file system"?** Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло то, что я "переехал" в другую папку - вместо "`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxxx/files/`" в папку "`/data/user/0/xxxxx/files/`". Эту папку я нашел, посмотрев значение `RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration.DatabasePath`.

Таким образом, нужно заменить

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

на

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration.DatabasePath)
```